How to prove that the images of universal morphisms from a free group to subgroups are all identical?
On pp. 81-82 of his Algebra: Chapter 0, Paolo Aluffi gives two different definitions for the subgroup $\left<A\right>$ of a group $G$ generated by some arbitrary subset $A\subseteq G$.
He first defines $\left<A\right>$ as the image of the unique group homomorphism $\varphi_A:F(A)\to G$, where $F(A)$ is the free group on $A$.
Then, later, he (re-)defines $\left<A\right>$ as the intersection of all the subgroups of $G$ that contain the set $A$.
At no point does Aluffi attempt to prove the equivalence of these two definitions.
Maybe the reason for this reticence is that, it this point in the book, Aluffi has not yet developed enough of the category-theoretical machinery to give a formal proof.  By this point he has not yet introduced functors, for example.  This may limit his ability to formally express an argument involving two different categories, $\textbf{Grp}$ and $\textbf{Set}$.
Be that as it may, I would like to see the simplest possible proof of the equivalence of these two definitions for $\left<A\right>$.
Below is as far as I've been able to take it.

Let $G$ be an arbitrary group, and let $A$ be an arbitrary subset of $G$.
Let $F(A)$ be the free group on $A$, and $k:A \to F(A)$ its canonical inclusion.
Let $\{H_\alpha\}$, where $\alpha$ ranges over some (otherwise unimportant) index set $\mathcal{A}$, be the family of all subgroups of $G$ that contain the set $A$.
For some (otherwise unimportant) index set $\mathcal{A}$, let $\{H_\alpha | \alpha \in \mathcal{A}\}$ be the family of all the subgroups of $G$ that contain the set $A$.  For each $\alpha \in \mathcal{A}$, let $i_\alpha:A \to H_\alpha$ be the inclusion of the set $A$ into the subgroup $H_\alpha$.
For each $H_\alpha$, the universal property of free groups guarantees that there exists a unique group homomorphism $\varphi_\alpha:F(A)\to H_\alpha$ such that $\varphi_\alpha \circ k = i_\alpha$.
Now I would like to show, using category-theoretical arguments, that all the images $\text{Im}(\varphi_\alpha) = \varphi_\alpha(F(A))$ are identical.

The desired assertion seems to me obvious when I think about the situation described above from a set-theoretical point of view, but I don't know how to express this obvious fact using only category theory.
I know that in category theory it is common for questions of identity to be replaced by questions of isomorphism.  In this case, one would just show that all the $\text{Im}(\varphi_\alpha)$ are isomorphic as groups, and be done with it.
But this seems to me not to go far enough.  I want to show that the $\text{Im}(\varphi_\alpha)$ are identical as sets.  I lack the right language for this.

If you really want an abstract nonsense proof, it's an application of the adjoint functor theorem for posets. (We only need the codomain to be posetal to apply the construction.) But the set theoretic argument is fine.

The correct language is very simple: just prove that the two subgroups are isomorphic. Subgroups are not groups, they are defined as a monomorphism into a group. They form a category $\mathrm{Sub}(G)$ whose objects are subgroups $H \hookrightarrow G$, and morphisms are commutative triangles. Different subgroups $H_1, H_2 \hookrightarrow G$ can have isomorphic underlying groups $H_1 \cong H_2$. But if they are isomorphic as subgroups, then they really correspond to the same subgroup in the set-theoretic sense.
You can define many "set-theoretic" constructions on subgroups. There are at most one morphism between any two subgroups, so if there is a morphism, we say one subgroup contains the other. Intersections are just products in $\mathrm{Sub}(G)$. The coproduct of two subgroups $H, K$ in the category is given by $⟨H \cup K⟩$. The image of a homomorphism $\phi : G' \to G$ is also a subgroup (which is not a group!) It is defined with a universal property, that is the smallest subgroup $H \hookrightarrow G$ such that $\phi$ factors as $G' \to H \hookrightarrow G$. By virtue of being a monomorphism, the factorization is necessarily unique.
With these definitions you should be able to prove everything you want by some trial and error. Your title asks for a proof but your question only asks for a language for the proof, so I'll stop here and let you finish the actual proof.

Although phrasing it in terms of free groups is perhaps a slightly more abstract way of expressing it, the two descriptions of the subgroup of a group $G$ generated by a subset $A \subseteq G$ are just the natural "top down" and "bottom up" description of any mathematical structure generated by a subset. What is normally expressed as the "formal definition" is where $\langle A \rangle$ is defined as $I_A:=\bigcap_{A\subseteq H} H$ where $H$ runs over all subgroups of $G$ which contain $A$.
The more concrete description of $\langle A \rangle$ is that it consists of all of the elements of $G$ which can be written as a word of finite length in the letters $\{a, a^{-1}: a \in A\}$. But this is exactly saying that $\langle A \rangle = \text{im}(\varphi_A)$ where $\varphi_A \colon F(A) \to G$ where $\varphi_A$ is the homomorphism corresponding to the inclusion map.
To see that $\text{im}(\varphi_A)= I_A$ note that if $\iota_H\colon H\hookrightarrow G$ is a subgroup of $G$ and $A\subseteq H$. Then if $j_A \colon A \to H$ is the inclusion of $A$ in $H$, the universal property of $F(A)$ shows that there is a unique homomorphism $\psi_A \colon F(A) \to H$.
Since $\iota_H\circ j_A = i_A$ the inclusion of $A$ into $G$. it follows that $\iota_G \circ \varphi_{A,H} = \varphi_{A,G}$, that is, the canonical map $\varphi_{A,G}\colon F(A) \to G$ factors through $\iota_H\colon H \to G$ where $H$ is any subgroup of $G$ containing $A$. It then follows from the definitions that  $\varphi_A (F(A)) \subseteq I_A$.
But the image of a group homomorphism is always a subgroup of the target group, hence $\varphi_A(F(A) = I_A$ as required.
